# openweb icons conflicting with font awesome icons

Tags: css, font-awesome

I was using font awesome icons and it was working well.
When i needed some more icons i downloaded open web icons.
Now i copied openweb icons to my project and its related css also.

Font awesome css is having some rule like this..

```
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  *margin-right: .3em;
}
```

OpenWeb icons css is having some rule like this..

```
    [class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before {
    font-family: 'OpenWeb Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    vertical-align: center;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
}
```

So now, icons classes starts with "icon-"

> Example `<i class="icon-geo"></i>`

now "icon-" makes conflict as both icons are making there own rules based based on it..
I can see it in bugzilla..
if i commented one of its font family, other font will work..

How should i overcome this problem..

Comment: The easiest way is to hard code another prefix for openweb icons, such as `iconwf-`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easy to just pre/postfix the class with a different identifier:

```
[class^="iconOW-"]:before, [class*=" iconOW-"]:before {
             ^^                          ^^
font-family: 'OpenWeb Icons';
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: inherit;
vertical-align: center;
font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
}
```

You can then include them as you need to from a different class.

There are a number of web-font consolidation services that you might want to consider - [fontello.com](http://fontello.com) is one, which allows you to combine different icon-fonts (similar to and that includes [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)), but that doesn't currently include the [open web icons](http://pfefferle.github.io/openwebicons/) font you're using.

Ping them and they may well include it - given the value the font set offers!